# git checkout from bash script and from terminal behaves differently

Tags: bash, git, terminal, checkout

I am trying to do a regression test of my code using git and a bash script.
So I have written a script to run a sample with the current version and with some previous version.
The source files are located in the `src` directory, and samples are in the `samples` directory.
Both the `src` and `samples` directories are tracked by git under the same project.

I want to roll back only `src` files and not touch files in `samples`.
I have tried `git reset` and `git checkout`.

Problem:
When I go to `src` in terminal and type:

```
git checkout -- *.F90
```

It does what is should - it changes only Fortran files in this directory.

If I do the same command in a bash script, it changes everything: files in `src` and in `samples`! Like if it is run from the main directory, as `git checkout` or `git reset origin/master`... How can it be?

Somewhere I have found suggestion to use `env -i` in a script, but it did not work either.

The whole script is about 500 lines, here is the git related part:

```
cd $dsrc                   # go to src directory
ls                         # debuging, just to see , that I am there
git stash
git checkout origin/master -- *.F90
```

with the `ls` command I do see the source files, so I know I am in the right place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) for "pathspec":

> [...] in particular, `*` and `?` **can** match directory separators.

So `*.F90` matches all `.F90` files everywhere. To limit to the current directory, you could use

```sh
git checkout origin/master -- "$PWD"/*.F90
```

Notice that (as pointed out by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in their comment) the manual refers to what *Git* does. If the *shell* can expand the glob first, it will – for example, if there are files in the current directory that *do* match `*.F90`.

Only when there aren't any will Git get the unexpanded literal `*.F90` and match the `*` with any prefix, including `/`. To prevent expansion by the shell, you could quote the glob:

```sh
git checkout origin/master -- "$PWD/*.F90"
```

or use `.` in the pathspec:

```sh
git checkout origin/master -- ./*.F90
```

Comment: Note that sh/bash will expand `*.F90` to the files that do exist in `$PWD`, which sidesteps the problem in most cases. **But** (and this is obviously what is biting @MikhailModestov) if there *are no* `*.F90` files, bash/sh just passes the literal text `*.F90` to Git. You can also use `./*.F90` here: I tend to prefer that myself, but whatever works is fine. :-)

Comment: @torek Good point – the behaviour described by the Git manual refers to whatever there is after shell parameter expansion; unlike for many commands, you could even quote  `'*.F90'` because Git does its own expansion, and that expansion is different from shell expansion (where `*` does *not* match `/`).

Comment: Let me amend that.